# Programming Language and API for a Web Game Server

Tags: web, server, nonblocking

I am building a browser-based low latency game(tetris battle). 
Since it is a battle, at least two user need to be synchronized when the battle begins. I decided to use a cocos2d-js(javascript) for a client, however, I am not quite sure about the server since I don't have much experience this field.

Since I want to afford as many people as possible, I am considering non-blocking IO. For the server, what programming language and APIs are recommended for this kind of task?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a RESTfull API, distributing the view processing to the client side.

Well, any language can do it.  Java and C# seems nice options, C++ may do the trick too.  Choose one language that you're more confortable as you'll probably do better code.

Like many other problems on the world, the architecture is more important than the language you choose.  Surely the language impacts, I would not recommend Ruby on Rails in this case(for example), or many frameworks because they add lots of stuff that you won't need, making your application slower.

Take a look at http://zeromq.org/.  Its a powerfull protocol and far as can remember, making non-blocking IO is easier, I've used with java a long time ago and was very effective.